# The "ok" button in the popup that appears for low rep users when answering is misaligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, popup

[image: SCREENSHOT]

As shown by the red arrow in the image above, the <kbd>ok</kbd> button is not properly aligned.

Comment: To reproduce this, log out, click the answer text box from any question and you'll see the wrong alignment of the ok button in the popup. There isn't a need to log out if you have low reputation.

Comment: Honestly, does it really matter?

Comment: @mmking , No, It isn't much disturbing... But I just shared this bug with the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough to fix.

With you in the next build.

Comment: This seems to be affected for all the SE communities.(at least the ones I've tried). So, will the fix fix the problem in all the SE sites?

Comment: Yes. The fix is global.